# Only some TailwindCSS classes work after installation

Tags: tailwind-css

I just installed TailwindCSS and would like to learn about it. After some problem-solving during installation, I meanwhile had no more warnings in the installation process, but when now trying in VSCode some of the first examples from the Tutorial, some of the Tailwind classes used in the HTML file can be applied and have an effect in the browser, while others seemingly cannot be applied and have no effect in the browser.

Could anyone please help me, what needs to be done to make the TailwindCSS installation fully work and be able to make use of all Tailwind classes?

For example, this very first example from the tutorial on the Tailwind homepage works correctly for me and the button is correctly shown in blue and gets darker, when hovering over it in my browser (MacOS, Safari):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="tailwindout.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <button class="bg-sky-500 hover:bg-sky-700">
            Save changes
          </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

But one of the next examples in the tutorial on the homepage has no effect and the selected text is not shown in fuchsia color in my browser (MacOS, Safari), neither when calling the html file with live server from VSCode nor when directly opening the html file in the browser from the Mac Finder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="tailwindout.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="selection:bg-fuchsia-300 selection:text-fuchsia-900">
            <p>
              So I started to walk into the water. I won't lie to you boys, I was
              terrified. But I pressed on, and as I made my way past the breakers
              a strange calm came over me. I don't know if it was divine intervention
              or the kinship of all living things but I tell you Jerry at that moment,
              I <em>was</em> a marine biologist.
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does just `bg-fuchsia-300` (without variant) works?

Comment: The most likely reason the changes you're making aren't showing are either the output isn't being updated (not watching for changes or rebuilding) or caching (your browser isn't pulling a new copy of the output file). Try a hard refresh.

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka No, only referencing class=„bg-fuchsia-300“ doesn‘t work, as there is also no such class in the CSS output file.

Comment: @NathanDawson I‘m not sure, which output you mean, but the HTML file is definitely being updated in the browser. The CSS file though is static and doesn‘t update. It has been created initially at the end of the installation process by running „npx tailwindcss -i input.css -o output.css — watch“ and doesn‘t change, no matter, which classes I use in the HTML file, but I‘m not sure, if this is correct?

Comment: Make sure you have the content set in your config file. The CSS output file should be updating to reflect the classes you're using. If it hasn't updated since the first run, it won't include the latest styles you're using.

Comment: @NathanDawson Thanks, after some additional attempts today, the CSS output file now updates, although I haven‘t changed any settings anywhere, so I guess therefore at least the config file seems to be correct. But for some reason, it now only updates, when I run the `ndx tailwindcss -i … -o … — watch` command manually each time (although I already attached the watch parameter and it should update automatically after modifying the HTML file), otherwise it won‘t update.

Is there a possible explanation for that? I use VS Code to modify the files and run the terminal commands, by the way.